# Trying to set function as parameter

Tags: python

I'm trying to create function that get a number and return function. For example:

```
>>> const_function(2)(2)
2
>>> const_function(4)(2)
4
```

How can I return function as output? I've tried to write this:

```
def const_function(c):
    def helper(x):
        return c
    return helper(x)
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Because you are calling the enclosing function with argument `x` while you don't pass the argument `x` to your function. For creating a factory function you shouldn't call it inside the function. Like this `return helper`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
return helper
```

When you do:

```
return helper(x)
```

it calculates the result of `helper(x)` and returns it. When you `return helper` it will return the function itself.

Answer (score 8):

You're returning the result of calling the function. If you want to return the function itself, simply refer to it without calling it:

```
def const_function(c):
    def helper(x):
        return c
    return helper # don't call it
```

Now you can use it with the desired results:

```
>>> const_function(2)
<function const_function.<locals>.helper at 0x0000000002B38D90>
>>> const_function(2)(2)
2
>>> const_function(4)(2)
4
```